# How to create a custom UI for android and desktop java

Tags: java, android, graphics

im trying to make a cross-platform game using java. I hope it to be completly compatible with android and desktop. I think the best option is creating a "master" library project and then the one for android and for desktop. This works for logic and I can create a bitmap and a BufferedImage that shows using the respective view . Now,  my question is how to create a custom view that let me directly call it on the main class ( activity) and completly use my library? So in general,  to add a custom view in the "master" project and call it on android and on desktop

Answer (score 0):

Download 'Android Studio' and follow its tutorials for creating an android app.
Practice creating tictactoe game (this tutorial should be everywhere).
You don't have to use android studio, but it's definitely friendlier than eclipse.